# How to change the list of default error parsers in new Eclipse CDT projects

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I was able to use [`plugin_configuration.ini`](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html#preferences_plugin.ini) to set the `org.eclipse.cdt.core/errorparser.default.ids` preference. That worked for the workspace settings, but new projects are still created with a different set of error parsers enabled, and since project settings override workspace settings I still need to manually change the collection of error parsers for every new project.

Comment: I'm not sure but if you go to Window->Preferences->C/C++->New C/C++ Project Wizard->Makefile Project->Error Parsers you get to choose default error parsers

Comment: Thanks, @gvd. I should have clarified that that was the first thing I tried. Those are the "Workspace settings" referred to in the question.

Comment: It does say that they are applied only when no toolchains are selected

Comment: That is the answer, thanks. Once I created a project with no existing toolchain, the settings were preserved. The use of plugin_configuration.ini is not even required. The setting from the GUI persists.

I could not find that information either in the dialog or in the doc. Could you please add a link to where you found the information as an answer? I'll mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Leo I just opened the settings and had a look (Window->Preferences->C/C++->New C/C++ Project Wizard->Makefile Project->Error Parsers). There was a description in right above the error parser selection regarding the "only works if no toolchain is selected". Ah, I just found a [help page](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_newproj_parser_error.htm) that shows the same thing.

Comment: Aha! Didn't think to look there, thanks! I see your comment above now... I was looking under the Workspace Build settings.